# Objective-c UIView and UIVewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am novice in programming in objective-c. I have a question with UIView and UIViewController. I add UIViewController to my storyboard after that I create objective-c class(TestController) subclass of UIViewController. It is possible draw(CGRect) in from TestController? Because I wanna move with this rect later. Thank you for replies.

Comment: Each view controller has a UIView that covers the whole area of the view controller.  You can subclass that UIView and draw on it using the `drawRect` method.

Comment: Yes but Why It doesnt work when I add - `(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect `to UIViewController. It show nothing. Full example [link](http://pastebin.com/sBjSabkY)

Comment: The `UIViewController` class does not have a `drawRect` method.  Only the `UIView` class has a `drawRect` method.  By adding a `drawRect` method to your view controller subclass, you've defined a method that the framework will never call.

Comment: Can you help how call method drawRect from method drawLevel because i dont know what argument is `(CGRect)rect`

Comment: If you have an outlet to the UIView, like `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *someView;` then you call drawRect with `[self.someView setNeedsDisplay];`

Comment: I managed all but it doesnt work. Edited code -> [link](http://pastebin.com/K0DPSg7k)